# MIPS Pipeline, trying to understand something about BEQ

Tags: mips, pipeline

One of the exercises that my teacher tends to include in all of his tests is "Draw the MIPS Pipeline with/without BEQ anticipation". That's a direct translation (English's not my mother tongue), and I can't seem to find anything about this "BEQ anticipation" on the Internet, be it in Italian or English (using the direct translation as the search term in the latter case).
Any help?

Comment: I think the word you want is "prediction".

Comment: That was it, thank you!